# How is an on ground lightning strike test conducted?

Tags: safety, weather, avionics, aircraft-certification, lightning

Whenever a design company is obtaining an STC for an aircraft (Supplemental Design Certificate) for an electrical installation, one of the required tests to obtain the STC is a lightning strike test. The test is needed to show that the electronics installed can withstand a lightning strike without degrading their performance or inducing degradations into other systems.

We can't position the aircraft on ground waiting for a lightning bolt to hit like 'Doc' in 'Back to the Future', so how do design companies, or engine manufacturers, etc. simulate a lightning strike and draw conclusive results that the system with withstand actual lightning?

Comment: If you can find some local Tesla coil enthusiasts around your area that will generally be more than happy to fire off the type of voltage/current combinations at whatever you'll let them. Could even sit inside it like in the image below since it's basically acting as a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You create your own lightning. You can do that with an [impulse generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_generator). Here's what a smaller one looks like:

[image: impulse generator]

I don't know if that's what is used for the certificates but it certainly one way to test against lightning strikes (provided that you can generate a high enough voltage).

Comment: I am not positive but I think only the aircraft manufacturer uses very high voltage (enough to damage the aircraft) only on the Type Certificate.  Whereas other lightning strike tests use lower non-damaging tests, then by measuring the resulting currents one can mathematically simulate the full voltage by simply multiplying the measurements accordingly.  I only heard this from word of mouth though from an engineer at Rolls Royce.

Answer (score 4):

So, [Lightning Strike Test - Panthera Aircraft by Pipistrel - Episode 1](http://youtu.be/0Nly5GbDHfA) is a short video showing how Pipistrel did it. I really want to be able to push that button! :)

This [page](http://www.nasa.gov/larc/lightning-tests/) is a video and article showing how NASA does it.

Here is a [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-happens-when-lightni/) article about the why's more than the how's.

Comment: The videos both show testing just a separate bits of skin, while the electronics needs to be tested with the complete airframe.

Comment: +1 for interesting info on skin tests but as Jan mentioned I am thinking more in terms of installation onto an airframe where the lightning strikes the frames.

Comment: @esé there are facilities that can hold a small plane and fire lightning at it

Comment: Please add more than just links to your answer. Quoting the help center's [How do I write a good answer?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." In this case, include a brief summary or quote describing each method.