# What tests are done on aircraft wings for testing the effects of lightning?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-development, lightning

During the testing phase of aircraft wings, there are lot of testing like temperature, pressure, humidity, vibration and load/stress. Apart from these, does any one have idea which other tests are done on them for complete qualifications like like lightning?

Comment: Your question is more applicable nowadays. 20 years ago, the airplane were enterely made of aluminium and were design to actually be a easy path for lightings as they were made of metal, the lighting was passing by. However, with the increasing composite composition of an airplane your question becomes really sensible where the lighting path goes though a composite not prepare for electricity (there are some tricks here...)

Comment: There is a difference between the title (only lightning tests) and the body (which *other* tests, like lightning). So are you interested only in lightning tests or any certification tests?

Comment: I have edited the question as other commented said apart from what all the categories I have said, only lightning is left. But if you know of any other tests, and if you explain them, that will be beneficial for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all the tests done on aircraft wings can easily be categorized in one of the areas you mentioned.

<strike>The only remaining thing I can think is bending an aircraft's wing. It is [stated on BBC](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20140319-stress-tests-for-safer-planes) as:</strike>

> Many modern passenger jets can flex their wings nearly 90 degrees in a test rig.

For B787, [it is reported](http://www.wired.com/2010/03/boeing-787-passes-incredible-wing-flex-test/):

> During the test, the wings on the 787 were flexed upward
>   “approximately 25 feet” which equates to 150 percent of the most
>   extreme forces the airplane is ever expected to encounter during
>   normal operation. The test is used to demonstrate a safety margin for
>   the design and is part of the certification process to show the
>   airplane can withstand extreme forces.

[This video shows](https://youtu.be/sA9Kato1CxA) (also [this one](https://youtu.be/Ai2HmvAXcU0)) how much force a wing can take before breaking.

OP [asked](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/what-tests-are-done-on-aircraft-wings-apart-from-temperature-pressure-humidity#comment34253_14750) about tests for lightning effects. Lightning commonly strikes the nose, wingtips, engine cowlings, and tip of the vertical tail. Hence, wings are not the only parts of an airplane which needs to be *protected* against lightning.

To avoid reinventing the wheel, please see the following questions:

- [How is an on ground lightning strike test conducted?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3836/65)
- [What happens when an airplane gets struck by lightning?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/888/65)

Comment: I would consider that part of the load and stress testing.

Comment: I am wondering what tests are done to check if lighting will affect the wings ?

Comment: @NitinG If you are talking about lighting on wings, please look at [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64/65). However, I suspect you are [talking about lightning](http://libroediting.com/2012/12/07/lightning-lightening-or-lighting/).

Comment: @NitinG that's a good question. I believe those tests are done on the components and not the whole wing.

Comment: @NitinG If you're really asking about light(n)ing testing, then it would be best to edit your question and add that. It would make the question much more specific and therefore it would be easier to get a good answer.

Comment: Question edited but lightning is only one thing, any other tests are still done on them apart from what I have mentioned.